# java project deployed on Google Cloud

Tags: spring, mongodb, gcloud

I have deployed a  java project on Google Cloud. I am using MongoDB and I have created MongoDB cluster and finished with the installation of the db. However, the db is not working.Can you guide me how to fix it?

Comment: Need more details. do you have any error?

Comment: As @KarthikeyanVaithilingam mentioned, we need more information to be able to help. I would also invite you to give this [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a read to help you in formulating a good question.

Comment: Error:There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException

Comment: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]